# Can dash.js use segments from different video files?

Tags: video, dash.js

I have a number of mp4 files that I want to connect together on the client and play as one contiguous video with a soundtrack that plays over them. It seems like dash.js might be the tool for the job, but all the examples I've seen so far split a *single* mp4 into segments. Can I use dash.js to play many mp4 files as if they were a single file? I'm guessing I'd have to convert the mp4 files into some other format - which is fine.

Answer (score 0):

"Can I use dash.js to play many mp4 files as if they were a single file?"
No. Dash.js only plays .mpd manifest files.

Suggest you use mp4box to concatenate your multiple mp4s in to a single mp4, then use mp4box to package that file in to a dash presentation, which dash.js will play after you mount the manifest and media files on a web server.

Comment: The manifest file points to individual files for each segment, does it not? Could you have segment files in the manifest that originated from two or more mp4 files?

Comment: Yes. As long as segment duration and other meta data are compatible you can theoretically edit the Representation Sets to achieve this. Its almost the same concept as how DAI(Dynamic Ad Insertion works)